# Model is null when url.action is called in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

My model have List products which get from database.
When index view loaded, i get the variable from input of user, then model get varible, and return view OutputTableAsync. After view loaded, i click link "Export Excel", in debug mode, List products is null.

My view:

```
<body>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        var products = Model.products.Products;
        <a href="@Url.Action("ExportToExcel","Home", new {products = products })">Export Excel</a>
        <table border="1" style="width: 100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Model</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Link</th>
                    <th>ImageUrl</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var product in Model.products.SortProduct())
                {
                    <tr id="i">
                        <td align="center">@product.Model</td>
                        <td align="center">@product.FormatPrice()</td>
                        <td align="center"><a href="@product.Link">@product.Link</a></td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="@product.ImageUrl" style="width : 200px; height:200px ;" id="@product.ImageUrl" /></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
</body>
```

ExportToExcel method in controller:

```
public void ExportToExcel(List<Product> products)
{
    ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Products");
    ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Model";
    ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "Price";
    ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "Link";
    ws.Cells["D1"].Value = "ImageLink";
    int rowstart = 2;
    foreach(var item in products)
    {
        ws.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", rowstart)].Value = item.Model;
        ws.Cells[string.Format("B{0}", rowstart)].Value = item.Price;
        ws.Cells[string.Format("C{0}", rowstart)].Value = item.Link;
        ws.Cells[string.Format("D{0}", rowstart)].Value = item.ImageUrl;
        rowstart++;
    }
    ws.Cells["A:AZ"].AutoFitColumns();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment: filename=" + "ExcelFile.xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Did you observe the generated markup in browser after you run your code?

Answer (score 0):

According to accepted answer [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2017595.aspx?How%20to%20pass%20object%20of%20class%20in%20url%20action%20in%20mvc%20C%20) you can not pass complex type through `Url.Action`

I would pass serialized version of object in this situation.